# Rede Neural em R - Dados de Entrada

Tags: r, filtro, redes-neurais

Estou tendo um problema nos dados de entrada de uma rede neural, estou trabalhando com entradas de 5000 pares de números, estes números são deslocamentos em X e Y, ou seja, com base no frame anterior e no frame atual consigo ver qual foi o deslocamento e assim ter um sinal que representa o movimento. A imagem abaixo mostra uma pequena amostra de uma das entradas que devo utilizar para treinamento da rede.

```
 x,y
-0.00351363, 0.000967466
0.139664, 0.0312345
0.175774, -0.00378994
0.458393, 0.116977
0.241508, -0.000456899
0.144307, 0.0148827
0.251653, 0.000391103
0.00184657, 0.0477789
0.026319, 0.0212102
0.179847, 0.0699048
0.245969, 0.0124811
0.0526478, -0.0191692
0.067206, 0.0421046
0.0491242, -0.0203557
0.348096, -0.0346274
0.134959, -0.132013
0.162158, 0.017853
0.121126, 0.0325144
0.215919, 0.0808862
0.152572, 0.0224511
0.743098, -0.0271121
0.442534, -0.00596414
0.323115, 0.0267839
```

Ao plotar os 5096 valores de X e Y, é gerado o seguinte gráfico:[image: Plot]

Minha questão é, esses dados são valores de deslocamento de pixels, resumindo estou analisando um movimento especifico em um vídeo, nesse movimento armazeno o deslocamento que todos os pixels fizeram, tenho o intuito de treinar uma rede neural para detectar esse mesmo movimento em outros vídeos. A questão é como posso passar essa informação para a rede neural, pois preciso informar que esses valores (que são exatos 5096 pares) correspondem ao movimento que desejo detectar, assim como tenho movimentos semelhantes mas não são o que desejo detectar (seria um treinamento supervisionado). Como posso passar esses dado para a rede, pois até hoje só treinei rede em series temporais e nesse caso seria varias entradas com 5096 valores e se esses valores representam ou não o movimento.

Ex:

Entrada 1: (5096 valores de X),(5096 valores de Y),(True)

Entrada 2: (5096 valores de X),(5096 valores de Y),(False)

Entrada N: ...

**Atualização 1**

Para simplificar o problema de possuir dois sinais, fiz a resultante dos vetores e assim obtendo apenas um gráfico.[image: Resultante]

Porem é perceptível que seria muito "desgastante" para qualquer rede neural se ajustar a isso, sendo assim apliquei um filtro de sinal para suavizar.
Utilizando a biblioteca ***signal***, apliquei o seguinte filtro:

```
resultante <- fftfilt(rep(1, 50)/50,resultante)
```

E com isso obtive o seguinte resultado: 
[image: Resultante após aplicação do filtro]

Agora estou com problemas em treinar a rede MLP, **pois ao que parece não posso passar uma lista para ela**. Meus dados estão organizados da seguinte forma:

[image: Primeira linha do data frame]

Código MLP:

```
redeCA<-mlp(df$dados, df$saida, size=nNeuronios, maxit=maxEpocas, initFunc="Randomize_Weights",
            initFuncParams=c(-0.3, 0.3), learnFunc="Std_Backpropagation",
            learnFuncParams=c(0.1), updateFunc="Topological_Order",
            updateFuncParams=c(0), hiddenActFunc="Act_Logistic",
            shufflePatterns=F, linOut=TRUE)
```

Erro:

```
Error in checkInput(x, y) : 
  'x' has to be numeric, after a conversion to matrix
```

---

Comment: Por favor não poste dados (ou código) como imagens. Edite **a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(head(dados, 20))`. Além disso, qual o critério para transformar dados bivariados contínuos em dados univariados binários? Assim só é impossível de responder.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Algumas perguntas que podem ajudar a obter uma respostas: O que são os seus dados? Qual a sua unidade amostral? O que você está tentando prever? Dito isso, em geral em redes neurais usamos `arrays` multidimensionais para representar os dados.

Comment: Esses dados são valores de deslocamento de pixel, seria a movimentação que os pixels estão fazendo frame a frame de um vídeo. No caso preciso treinar a rede com varias entradas que representem um movimento para que depois a rede consiga detectar se houve ou não aquele movimento em especifico. O problema está em como juntar todas essas informações, onde cada elemento é composto por 5096 valores de X e Y e representar a qual grupo esses valores pertencem.

Comment: sim, mas qual é sua unidade amostral? você só temem vídeo ou tem vários? qual é sua variável resposta?

Comment: Descolamento em unidade de pixel, delta x e delta y. Possuo varias vídeos com o movimento que desejo detectar e outros com movimentos semelhantes, esse movimento dura em media 3 a 5 segundos, seria um treinamento supervisionado. Minha variável de saída seria 1 ou 0, para quando a rede treinada verificar um novo vídeo, possa retornar que houve ou não o movimento.

Comment: Confesso que ainda não entendi o que são esses deslocamentos... Você possui cada frame desse vídeo?

Comment: Utilizando a técnica Optical Flow denso de Farneback, eu consigo o deslocamento que cada pixel fez em relação ao frame anterior, a técnica analisa o vídeo frame a frame calculando para onde cada pixel se moveu. Atualizei o post com alguns mudanças.